# How can i set position value to be same for every resolution on inital load?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, reactjs, pdf

I'm trying to figure out how can i set position be same value whether it renders first time on laptop or 1920x1080 monitor.

I'm using this as example - https://agentcooper.github.io/react-pdf-highlighter/# and as you can see inside text layer every div has same position whether it loads on laptop or on 1920x1080 monitor.

For example at this link just focus on one div and render it both on smaller screen and larger screen and you will see what i'm trying to achieve, both times they have same position values.

If you want to check live example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer  -- at this live example position value changes on each resolution.

I want to achieve this but so far i tried :

- Every kind of option from ng2-pdf-viewer library and none of them can help me achieve that for every load

  - fixed width for container wrapping pdf layer but that has no logic as when it renders again on 1920 it has different positions

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) **vw** or **vh** instead.

Comment: That is not actually what he / she wants to achieve i think